# How to plot 3D Graph in XYZ axis jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to plot a graph in my application. I am trying to plot a graph having 4 points which needs to be joined by lines. I tried with so many libralies such as canvasXpress.. But could not able to find the solution.

I had tried this much.

http://jsfiddle.net/rohitghatol/tn9sm/

```
var render = function(){
renderer.render(scene,camera);
}
render();
$("#container").append(renderer.domElement);
```

Now I have to draw 4 points with joining lines.

I am not getting how to scale and plot the lines in the graph.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: I had added the link. Please refer. @Cerbrus

Comment: I am new to this actually. Sorry for that. I am not getting how to give scaling and plotting points @Vidya G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution using Three.Js javascript library. Here's the snippet.
I had used the following code to create the grid helpers and it worked.

```
    var gridXZ = new THREE.GridHelper(100, 10);
    gridXZ.setColors(new THREE.Color(0x939393), new THREE.Color(0xbdbdbd));
    gridXZ.position.set(100, -.1, 100);
    scene.add(gridXZ);

    var gridXY = new THREE.GridHelper(100, 10);
    gridXY.position.set(100, 100, 0);
    gridXY.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
    gridXY.setColors(new THREE.Color(0x0066FF), new THREE.Color(0xCCE0F9));
    scene.add(gridXY);

    var gridYZ = new THREE.GridHelper(100, 10);
    gridYZ.position.set(0, 100, 100);
    gridYZ.rotation.z = Math.PI / 2;
    gridYZ.setColors(new THREE.Color(0xCC9900), new THREE.Color(0xF5EBCC));
    scene.add(gridYZ);
```

And for drawing the lines I had drawn the lines using three D points

```
    // Line one
    material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x000000
    });


    geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry.vertices.push(
        new THREE.Vector3(x1, y1, z1),
        new THREE.Vector3(x2, y2, z2)
    );

    line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
    scene.add(line);
```